# virtual memory and physical memory of the process will raise when data was allocated and released in different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory

I have a memory allocate problem  with  Ubuntu 18.04.
(1) i allocate some data  memory  in  thread 1,
(2) release the data  and allocate the same data to the same object again  in  thread 2,
then in the step(2) the virtual memory and physcial memory will be raise as twice as the memory in step(1) .  i have use the share_ptr to manage the memory, and also run the process with valgrind,so  i am sure there in no memory leak.  but i am wonder why the memory of the process will raise so much? is three any method to remove the memory raise?

there is my example code , with the two level hierarchical-pymrid structure, the top level is LGMemory with  a 2D vector of shared_ptr, the second level is the Patch Class which contain the real data.  the step(2) is execute in the LGMemory::updateData() in a thread.i have test different case in the code ,in  the case 1,3,5 the memory of process  raise  in steep (2), but in the case 2,4,6 , the memory  don't raise.why?
any hint about the problem will be great helpful for me ,thx~

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <set>
void waitFor(int n)
{
    int ii =n;
    while((ii--)>0)
    {
        sleep(1);
        continue;
    }
}

class Cell
{
    public:
 
    Cell(){};
    Cell(int x, int y){};
    ~Cell(){};

    private:

    double acc, va, mNew, vxy;
    std::vector<double> hitP;
    double a[5];
    double b[5];
    int n, visits, laser_count_, nNew, visitsNew, laser_count_NEW, firstMapId, firstMapIdNEW;
    std::set<int> hitedMapIds;
};
class Cell2{

    public:
    long a[10];
};

template<class T=Cell>
class Patch{
    public:
    Patch(){};
     Patch(size_t x, size_t y)
     {
        data_.resize(x);
        for(size_t ii=0; ii<data_.size();++ii)
        {
            data_[ii].resize(y);
        }
     };

    ~Patch()
    {
        for(size_t ii=0; ii<data_.size();++ii)
        {
            std::vector<T>().swap(data_[ii]);
        }
        std::vector<std::vector<T> >().swap(data_);
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<T> > data_; 
};

template<class T>
class LGMemory
{
    public:
    LGMemory();
    ~LGMemory();

    void resize(int xLen, int yLen);
    void fillData();
    void clearData();
    void updateData();
    int status_;
    std::thread* thread_;

    private:
    
    std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T> > > data_;
    int xLength_;
    int yLength_;
};

template<class T>
LGMemory<T>::LGMemory():thread_(nullptr),xLength_(0),yLength_(0),status_(0)
{
    data_.resize(xLength_);
    for(auto outVec:data_)
    {
        outVec.resize(yLength_);
        for(auto inItem:outVec )
        {
            inItem = NULL;
        }
    }
    thread_ = new std::thread(&LGMemory::updateData,this);
}

template<class T>
LGMemory<T>::~LGMemory()
{
    if(thread_)
    {
        delete thread_;
    }
    clearData();

}
template <class T>
void LGMemory<T>::resize(int xLen, int yLen)
{
    xLength_ = xLen;
    yLength_ = yLen;
    data_.resize(xLength_);
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < data_.size(); ++ii)
    {
        data_[ii].resize(yLength_);
        for (size_t jj = 0; jj < data_[ii].size(); ++jj)
        {
            data_[ii][jj] = NULL;
        }
    }
}

template<class T>
void LGMemory<T>::fillData()
{
    for(size_t ii=0; ii<data_.size();++ii)
    {
        for(size_t jj=0;jj<data_[ii].size();++jj)
        {
            data_[ii][jj] =std::make_shared<T>(32,32);
        }
    }

}

template<class T>
void LGMemory<T>::clearData()
{
    for(size_t ii=0; ii<data_.size();++ii)
    {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T> >().swap(data_[ii]);
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T> > >().swap(data_);
}

template<class T>
void LGMemory<T>::updateData()
{
    while(status_ != 5102)
    { 
        sleep(1);
        continue;
    }

    clearData();
    std::cout<<" updateData ,clear finish, wait for fill data..."<<std::endl;
    waitFor(1);
    resize(xLength_,yLength_);

    fillData();
    std::cout<<" updateData , fill data finish..."<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    std::cout<<"start test ..."<<std::endl;
    
    /// case 1 
    LGMemory<Patch< > > lg;
    lg.resize(50,50);
    
    //// case 2
    // LGMemory<Patch< > > lg;
    // lg.resize(100,100);

    //// case 3
    //LGMemory<Patch< Cell2 > > lg;
    //lg.resize(50,50);

    //// case 4
    // LGMemory<Patch< Cell2 > > lg;
    // lg.resize(100,100);

    ////case 5
    //LGMemory<Patch< long > > lg;
    //lg.resize(50,50);

    ////case 6
    //LGMemory<Patch< long > > lg;
    //lg.resize(100,100);


    lg.fillData();

    waitFor(10);
    std::cout<<" lg update data begin...."<<std::endl;
    lg.status_ =5102;
    /// updateData execute in another thread 
    // wait the updateData method execute finish. 
    waitFor(20);

    lg.thread_->join();
    return 0;
}
```

there is the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
Project(MemoryTest)

#find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
add_executable( MemoryTest MemoryTest2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MemoryTest  pthread )
```

Comment: In general, once a process has requested a chunk of memory from the OS, the process's memory-handling code will keep that chunk of memory around even when the program frees it, so that the next time the program allocates memory, the memory can be served/reused directly from the process's local memory-buffer-pool, without having to bother the OS again.   As long as your program's memory usage isn't constantly increasing over time, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: in my working code ,the data memory  usage in large,about 2G，the updateData method is called once ,but will lead the memory usage raise from  2G to almost 4G, which is critical when computing resources of the product is limit。So is there is any way to remove the memory usage raise ?

Comment: Your OS should handle this situation. When the memory requested by your greedy process is needed elsewhere (and not needed anymore in your process), it will be released for sure. High memory consumption by your applications is not the problem per se.

Comment: If it's causing real problems (i.e. more than just making the memory-tracker's display look ominous) you could try allocating a large chunk of RAM using a different mechanism such as memory-mapping ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory ) and then implement your own in-process/user-level heap-manager to dole out chunks of that memory-region to your code as necessary; then you could "really free" that RAM by deleting the shared-memory region.  It's a lot of work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not uncommon that memory managers use thread-local pools to avoid contention on some global data structure (which would need to be protected by a lock). So even if thread 1 releases its memory, this memory is only returned to the local memory pool of thread 1. Now if thread 2 wants to allocate some memory, it has to allocate its own pool.

I assume that you use the standard glibc malloc which is derived from [ptmalloc](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals). Alternatively you can try using some other memory manager like [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/), [tcmalloc](https://google.github.io/tcmalloc/overview.html), [Hoard](http://hoard.org/) or [mimalloc](https://microsoft.github.io/mimalloc/). Though most of them use thread-local pools (AFAIK), there are differences in how these are handled, so you will probably see differences in memory usage and performance.